# Playing around with a mobile app's IA

Tags: mobile, ios, information-architecture

I have an app which contains several features and among them payment.

A user selects the amount to pay, selects a payment method and then the payment occurs. After the payment occurs, we show the user a receipt page.

My question lies here: once I'm in payment mode, the back button in the mobile (iOS) will take the user to Home.

[image]

Once I'm at the receipt screen, can I have the back button take the user to order history or would that be too confusing to the users?

[image]

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe whatever the underlying human scenario is, just to understand what context is before and after? "Joe Blow has to do X, Y, Z so he launches the app, does A, B then C. He enters a payment amount, taps 'Pay', then confirms it, and then he sees a receipt and knows the payment went through." What I'm getting at is "confusing" will be relative to what makes sense for the user to do at that moment in context.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out! What would the user do next? The basic features of the app are in the bottom menu so (s)he can proceed to performing those tasks from the bottom. But once the user is done and is at the receipt page, what should they do next?!

So basically if there was a "Done" button, where would it lead the user to next?!!

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm asking you to describe the real human problem you're trying to design for, not the possible solution. Quick example: I'm interested in a stock I think might be undervalued, so I want to make sure by looking at the historical data and compare it to other companies in the same market or of the same size, same financials, etc. OR, I want to place a conditional order that executes if the stock hits a certain threshold. Note that I described tasks only, the human problems to solve. I omitted details of any app, the solution. Problem != solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be confusing, but again I'm not the user of this application. If you want to keep the structure the same I would suggest changing "Home" to "Cancel payment" and "History" could become "Previous payments" or "All receipts" not sure how to name it, but it should communicate that if I press it I go back to the list of receipts, hope that makes sense.

Also the best way to figure this out is to do some user testing, ask people to use the application, while thinking aloud. Make few tasks that involve payments/payment cancelation/viewing all receipts and observe how they use the application.  Ask them what they think about the text, does it confuse them, and what they expect to happen if they click the back button (before they click).

Comment: Thanks! Yes initially I had the "Home" breadcrumbs as "Back" which would lead the user to the previous step. I'm testing around the best way to go around this! 

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Are you committed to having a "back" button?" Is it not implicit in this context that "back" will put the flow in reverse?

With e-commerce and e-banking I often see 2 CTAs post-transaction like, "Home/Continue Shopping" and then "Order History/Payment History." I usually don't see "Back."

Amazon's mobile checkout receipt confirmation opens in a dialog (at least on iOS) with a small "Cancel" button that closes this dialog and then shows you that your cart is now empty. I confess that word "Cancel" appearing on an order receipt feels ambiguous. Am I cancelling the order? I know now that it doesn't, but the first time that was odd.

I don't think the word "History" is in appropriate, though the arrow is odd.

Comment: I may have not explained myself right. I actually was wondering if on completion of the transaction, instead of the breadcrumbs returning the user home, it would return them to the Orders History page. That's what I meant by history.